# Rewrite variable in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have my variable `mydata` which Im rewriting inside the `$http.post`. I would like to know how can I access the variable `mydata` outside the `$http.post`. If I do `console.log(mydata);` I am getting an error `undefined`.

```
.controller('MapCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicSideMenuDelegate, $cordovaGeolocation,$http) {

            var mydata; 

            $http.post('http://example.com').then(function(resp) {

                mydata = resp.data['somedata'];

            }, function(err) {
                .....
            })

            console.log(mydata);
        })
```

Comment: this is the how async call works...call back will call once it async call get succeed..the data return from the callback wouldn't be accessible outside the function..because synchronous execution does execute outer line first and then JavaScript compiler goes for the asynchronous calls

Comment: I see. Is there any workaround in order to get my data outside of the httppost?

Comment: simply you can't, you can get it only when the ajax gets succeed..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$http.post` is an asynchronous call. When you call `console.log()` on mydata, it has not been loaded yet, hence is `undefined`.

The variable `mydata` is in the controller scope because you defined it there, so you do have access to it, just it has not been assigned to `resp.data['somedata']` at the moment you called `console.log()`

If you put a `timeout` around your console log, such as `setTimeout(function(){ console.log(mydata) }, 100)` you will see the data.

Answer (score 2):

AngularJS `$http` is **ASYNC**, so when you log your result it hasn't been assigned yet.

You can try something like this to work with your data:

```
var mySuccessCallback = function(somedata){
   //I have my data here!
   console.log('Here is my response: ', somedata);

   //some awesome functionallity here...
   somedata = somedata + 1;    
}

var handleMyErrorPlease = function(response){
    console.log('Something really bad happened! :( ', response.error);
}

$http.post('http://myurl', myPayload)
   .success(mySuccessCallback)
   .error(handleMyErrorPlease);
```

You can read a lot more here: [AngularJS $http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the value as `undefined` because your ajax is making an `asynchronous` call, which means that until the response is finished the value will not be assigned. You can modify your `$http` call like so:

```
$http({ url: 'http://example.com',
        method: 'POST',
        async: false});
```